# webkit not cascading styles into svg's?

Tags: css, svg, webkit, cross-browser

I would like to hide/show part of an SVG (along with some other elements) by adding/removing a class of an outer div. This doesn't seem to be working cross-browser. Example doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>webkit non-cascading svg</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #shape1, #ul1
      {
          display: none;
      }
      #shape2, #ul2
      {
          display: none;
      }

      .show #shape1, .show #ul1
      {
          display: inline-block;
      }
      .show #shape2, .show #ul2
      {
          display: inline-block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>This svg should be hidden:</p>
      <svg width="100" height="100">
        <g id="shape1">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="40" height="20" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
        </g>
      </svg>
      <p>This ul should be hidden:</p>
      <ul id="ul1"><li>hidden list</li></ul>
    </div>

    <hr/>

    <div class="show">
      <p>This svg should be shown:</p>
      <svg width="100" height="100">
        <g id="shape2">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="40" height="20" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
        </g>
      </svg>
      <p>This ul should be shown:</p>
      <ul id="ul2"><li>shown list</li></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

testable at http://jsfiddle.net/unhammer/qA3BX/1/ – it works as intended in Firefox and Opera (Presto), but not in Chromium. Is my CSS wrong, or is this a bug in Chromium?

(Browsershots.org tells me Safari acts like Chromium.)

Comment: it seems like `display: inline-block` is the problem, at least it works if you replace it with `display: block`.

Comment: Aha, that solves it for my use at least, with only two extra lines added to my CSS. I guess Gecko/Presto interpret inline-block as block in SVG's, while Webkit ignores it. (I wish display were split into two features: binary hide/show vs how-to-display)

Comment: the SVG spec implies that all values except `display: none` mean that the element should be made visible. `inline-block` wasn't in CSS2.0 (which SVG 1.1 references), and because of that it wasn't listed in the SVG 1.1 spec.